# How to treat and test flow control if not with exceptions with c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

What's the right way to treat and test flow control on methods that are void if not with exceptions? I've seen that Microsoft do not recomend such practice so what's the right way?

This is how how I'm treating parameters that shouldn't be accepted in my method:

```
    public void RentOutCar(ReservationInfo reservationInfo) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reservationInfo.ReservationNumber) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reservationInfo.ReservationNumber))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Reservation Number is null or empty.");
            }
            if (reservationInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Null Reservation info.");
            }
            if (reservationInfo.Car == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("No car registered to rent.");
            }
            if (reservationInfo.RentalDatetime == DateTime.MinValue || reservationInfo.RentalDatetime == DateTime.MaxValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Rental Date has an unreal value.");
            }
            if (reservationInfo.Car.Mileage <0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Mileage can't be less than 0.");
            }

            reserverationsRegister.ReservationsDone.Add(reservationInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you say that Microsoft doesn't recommend such practice? And why does your code have no-op `catch`?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx

Comment: What's happening in your method is _not_ a control flow, it's just input validation.

Answer (score 5):

This is not what Microsoft mean when they say [you should not control flow with exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx).

> While the use of exception handlers to catch errors and other events
>   that disrupt program execution is a good practice, the use of
>   exception handler as part of the regular program execution logic can
>   be expensive and should be avoided.

In other words, you should not throw (and subsequently catch) exceptions in situations where the code in the `try` block is likely to throw and represents legitimate program logic.

A contrived example of controlling flow with exceptions may look like:

```
int x = GetUserInput();
try
{
    MustAcceptPositiveInput(x);
}
catch (InputIsNonPositiveException)
{
    MustAcceptNonPositiveInput(x);
}
```

The equivalent 'correct' code may look like:

```
int x = GetUserInput();
if (x > 0)
{
    MustAcceptPositiveInput(x);
}
else
{
    MustAcceptNonPositiveInput(x);
}
```

Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations, those which are not part of expected program execution. It results in more readable, less surprising and more performant code.

What you are doing in your code is fine (except for the redundant try-catch and faulty order of tests as @Clay mentions), you are validating inputs for exceptional values, those which your code **was not meant to handle**.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing an exception if the inputs are not valid is fine. Test reservationInfo for null first - or your other tests will break in unexpected ways. Also - no point in wrapping your tests in a try/catch if all you're going to do is rethrow it.

This is not a "control flow" issue as described in the article you put in the comments - and throwing exceptions is appropriate here.

You might consider wrapping just the "working code" in a try/catch, but only if you can recover from (or maybe log) any exceptions:

```
try
{
  reserverationsRegister.ReservationsDone.Add(reservationInfo);
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
  LogError( ex );
  throw;
}
```